# Broken pipe on tomcat startup

Tags: java, tomcat

Recently, our app began to be deployed significantly longer than before (startup time increased from about 1.5 minutes to about 3.5 minutes), because we switched to a slower server. When this slowdown had begun, a side effect started to appear. That's a chunk of my log:

```
2016-01-10 15:54:23.791 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 6314 ms
2016-01-10 15:54:52.933 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends com.kzoinnovations.service.restapi.dto.ResponseBaseErrorDTO> com.kzoinnovations.service.restapi.web.RestExceptionHandler.handle(java.lang.Exception,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:393) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.20]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.0.20]
```

As you can see, the error occurs in the thread `http-nio-8080-exec-2` in a half of minute after startup, but nobody makes HTTP requests from the outside.

We use Tomcat 8.0.20 and Java 1.8.0_31 (64 bit).

Comment: That thread will only be used if a request is being handled. Are you sure nobody made a request? How do you know?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz, the server was disconnected from the load balancer, which is the only source of HTTP requests. Also, I do not make requests, neither any script does.

Comment: Fortunately or not, but the error has stopped to be reproduced.